# what should a exist function return in c?

Tags: c

I have a function which should tell me if a resource exists. Should this function return 0 on exist, 1 on not-exist and -1 on an error or should it return 0 on exist and -1 on not existent /error?

Bodo

Comment: Neither. It should return TRUE on exists.

Comment: Question is about programming style, so should probably be on programmers.stackexchange.com rather than here.  Although I'd suggest the answer should be 1 if the resource exists and 0 otherwise (with some other mechanism to find error information).

Comment: Let us know what you tried up to now?

Comment: @Chinna: What do you expect one can try in this case. I've tried to return 1 and it felt good, then I tried to return 0. This was also a really good feeling...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the function is designed as a boolean, as indicated by a name such as `is_file_present()`, it should return 1 when the resource is present, so that it can be used in tests, such as:

```
if (is_file_present(...))
    ... open file ...

if (!is_file_present(...))
    ... print an error ...
```

On the other hand, if the function's real purpose are its side effects, and its result serve to indicate their success, it is acceptable to return 0 for the no-error case and an error code, such as -1, when there is an error. For example:

```
if (create_resource(...) == 0)
    ... resource has been created ...
else
    ... handle error ...
```

The use of -1 for error codes allows to use the same error convention for functions that return a count of items or an index.

Answer (score 0):

Like other people said it is about style. You can prefer to return 0 on non-existent and 1 on exists. Also for errors you can add an error or exception pointer pointer (** double stars)parameter to your function signature to indicate a failure. It can be a simple boolean or integer or a struct that contains detailed info about failure. Like an error code and message. This pattern occurs a lot in objective-c frameworks. Also AFAIK there is no exception stack in c so this approach may be the cleanest way to do it. I'd like to write some example code but i'm on mobile. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is not archaic and you can use the C99 standard, you could use the header `stdbool.h` and return `true` if the resource exist and `false` if the resource doesn't exist. That's a lot cleaner IMHO.